# What's the name of this song that often plays when Madara appears?

Tags: naruto, music

You can hear it at 2:08 in [this video](https://youtu.be/UlnvBBQPSDQ?t=128).

It often plays when Madara shows up but I couldn't find it anywhere. What's the name of the song?

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! Thanks for adding a timestamp to the video URL, so it starts at the right time; that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is this Madara Uchiha Theme - The God Awakened https://youtu.be/7m0IUJS-LOY